# Phabricator and Mercurial: arc amend not working because of "immutable local history"

Tags: mercurial, phabricator, arcanist

I'm trying to setup Phabricator with Mercurial for my team for Code Review. At this point I'm testing different scenarios, and I'm having problems with staked diffs.

Let's say I have rev 1 sent to review, and rev 2 stacked on rev 1. Now change requests come for rev 1. I did the changes and tried to run `arc amend`. It didn't work.

I got this message:

> Usage Exception: This project is marked as adhering to a conservative
>   history mutability doctrine (having an immutable local history), which
>   precludes amending commit messages.

**How can I make Mercurial allow me to amend unpublished revisions?**

Thank you!

Comment: Well, the message is quite clear although I have no experience with `arc`. Someone has chosen to disallow amending history. To fix this, allow it. Now, there is probably a way to explicitly force mercurial or arc to do this, but again, **someone** has chosen to disallow it. You might clear it with them first that what you want to do is really OK.

Comment: You're saying that this is an `arc` restriction? I thought it was a `mercurial` restriction.

Comment: Mercurial won't allow you to amend public changesets, that is those that you have already pushed somewhere (or you pulled in from somewhere). That message is not a Mercurial message. It can be found here - https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/86771333/ - which is part of Arcanist.

Comment: I know it is not a Mercurial message, but I thought it was caused by some Mercurial restriction.

Comment: If the changesets are in the draft phase, Mercurial will allow you to amend the last changeset. The actual error message you get is an arcanist message. It may be triggered by having public changesets in your repository though but you say "unpublished revisions" so I took that as meaning "draft".

Comment: So to clarify, when you say "unpublished revisions", what exactly does that mean?

Comment: The revisions are committed locally, but not pushed.

Comment: That should mean they are in the draft phase. In that case Mercurial should allow you to amend the last changeset, unless "arc amend" is something completely different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123327/discussion-between-gabitzish-and-lasse-v-karlsen).